# Adding fields to Laravel 5 authentication don't get inserted into the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been playing around with Laravel 5's out-of-the-box authentication. When I add fields to the schema and migrate, and then I make them fillable - those added fields don't get inserted into the database, the default fields get inserted but the new ones are blank. The form has been updated to include those new fields.

The console also shows that the form data is being sent correctly.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at the file `app/Services/Registrar.php`, you will find a `create` function in there:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

You need to modify this function to include your form fields. They will be passed in the `$data` array.

There is also a `validator` function in that file to apply validation rules to your fields.

Also, there is a `protected $fillable` array in the `app/User.php` model file. You will need to add your custom field names to this array so that they are mass-assignable.

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
```

**Edited July 9, 2015**

This is applicable to `v5.0.1`. The folder structure has changed going forward. The settings found in the `app/Services/Registrar.php` file have been moved to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`

Comment: Haha, I just saw that now as well. You beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: I cant find the `Services` folder inside `app`!

Comment: @blackops_programmer This is applicable to `v5.0.1`. They have changed the folder structure going forward. I think the settings found in the `app/Services/Registrar.php` file have been moved to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`

Comment: yeah you are right. I have just moved the validator and create methods inside my AuthController.php now and that does the job. I just found that out from my question I had posted here today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319556/where-is-the-registrar-services-in-laravel-5