# Where is the Registrar Services in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I added couple of fields to my user table and everywhere I read it said I also need to update the new fields in the `app/Services/Registrar.php` file. But I cannot find the `Services` folder anywhere! This is a new installation in Laravel 5 and here is the screen shot of my directory structure:

What happened to the Services Folder? When I test, I can see that the `User::create()` works but I dont know where its declared since I cant find the `Registrar.php` file.

[image]

Comment: It was removed in Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I added couple of fields to my user table and everywhere I read it said I also need to update the new fields in the app/Services/Registrar.php file.

This was removed in Laravel 5.1.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0

> Secondly, the `App\Services\Registrar` class used in Laravel 5.0 is no longer needed. You can simply copy and paste your validator and create method from this class directly into your `AuthController`. No other changes should need to be made to these methods; however, you should be sure to import the `Validator` facade and your `User` model at the top of your `AuthController`.

Comment: aha.. that makes sense now. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 2):

You are using 5.1 version and it doesn't have such directory or service. This version uses `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` traits for registering users.